# Ember observer not getting most recent value

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to observe a controller property in its associated view, but when I do so, I always get the old value. I know about the async issues with observers, as per:

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/

but using run.once() doesn't seem to help. Here's my code:

```
MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  testProperty: false,

  otherThingWatcher: function() {

    this.set('testProperty', true);
    console.log(this.get('testProperty')); // Outputs true when someOtherThing changes.

  }.observes('someOtherThing');

});

MyView = Ember.View.Extend({

  checkTestProperty: function() {

    console.log(this.get('controller.testProperty')); // Ack! This is false!

    var that = this;
    Ember.run.once(this, function() {

      console.log(this.get('controller.testProperty')); // Same thing.

    });

  }.observes('controller.testProperty');

});
```

What have I missed?

```
Versions:
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 ember.js:3521
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8+canary.503c75c9 ember.js:3521
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js:3521
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.9.1
```

Comment: The code above isn't valid javascript, which means it wouldn't even get to those logs, which might mean that you aren't showing the code that actually isn't working.

Comment: Sorry. I typed it from memory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. You need to use `extend`, not `Extend`
2. your observes can't end in a `;`

### Fixed Code

```
MyView = Ember.View.extend({

  checkTestProperty: function() {

    console.log(this.get('controller.testProperty')); // Ack! This is false!

    var that = this;
    Ember.run.once(this, function() {

      console.log(this.get('controller.testProperty')); // Same thing.

    });

  }.observes('controller.testProperty')

});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cixoqeqi/1/edit

Comment: My code was correct (just poorly typed from memory, sorry!), but looking through your JSBin led me to the real answer. Actual issue: my view was being rendered, then, after a sort, rerendered - which clobbered the property in question. Moving said variable to the parent (list) controller fixed the problem. Thank you!